# Eclipse: can double-click switch focus to the editor

Tags: eclipse

Is there a way in Eclipse to change focus to the editor when opening a file in Search or PyDev Package Explorer using a double-click? When I double click a match in Search (for instance), the focus stays in the search panel. Project Explorer does behave the way I would expect.

I'm using Luna SR2 (4.4.2).

Comment: That is what double click normally does. What is happening for you?

Comment: Ah ... thanks ... I see Project Explorer does work as expected. I've updated the question to ask about Search and PyDev Package Explorer.

Comment: Again Search behaves like this for me - but it might depend on exactly what type of search you are doing.

Comment: This seem to be some kind of bug or issue in my configuration. The double click worked correctly for Project Explorer, and then stopped working correctly. @greg-449, thanks for your comments.